# Posting multiple select list items to database with Asp.net Core Razor Pages

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am wanting to post all selected items from a list to a table, creating a new row for each of the selected items. I am having trouble posting multiple items at once however. I have tried to set up the tables to have a relationship using navigation properties but im rather new at this so cannot be sure where I have gone wrong. Currently I am able to post to the database, but only 1 record. The sticking point is posting multiple records to the TblReferrals table.

Please see below my model and page model set ups, so far

```
 public class TblReferrals
 {

     [Key]
     public string? IncidentId { get; set; }

     public string AssignmentNumber { get; set; } 
}

public class TblReferralStaff
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? AssignmentNumber { get; set; }

    public TblReferrals TblReferrals { get; set; }

    public string? IncidentId { get; set; }

}
```

My form

```
 <form method="post" id="newReferralForm">
    
     <div class="row my-md-3">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <label>Staff Names</label>                 
             <select class="form-control staffReferral" multiple="multiple" asp-items="@Model.EsrRecords" asp-for="@Model.ReferralStaff.AssignmentNumber">
                 <option></option>
             </select>
         </div>               
     </div>           
     <div class="row my-md-3">              
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <label>Incident Number</label>
             <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Referral.IncidentId" />
         </div>
     </div>
  
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
         <button class="btn btn-primary fw-bold createReferral">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

My Post request which is not complete, as this is the bit im kind of getting stuck on

```
   [BindProperty]
   public List<string> TblStaffList { get; set; }

   public SelectList EsrRecords { get; set; }

   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostNewReferral()
   {


       await _db.TblReferralStaff.AddRangeAsync(ReferralStaff);

       await _db.TblReferrals.AddAsync(Referral);
       await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

       return new JsonResult(ReferralStaff);


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code and description, You are setting a **one-to-many** relationship in your models https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many . Here is the modification.

> 1 The configuration of your models and dbcontext

**Tbl Model**

```
public class TblReferrals
{
    [Key]
    public string? IncidentId { get; set; }
    public string AssignmentNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TblReferralStaff> TblReferralStaffs { get; } = new List<TblReferralStaff>();
}

public class TblReferralStaff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? AssignmentNumber { get; set; }
    public TblReferrals TblReferrals { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? IncidentId { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class MultipleRecordsContext : DbContext
{
    public MultipleRecordsContext (DbContextOptions<MultipleRecordsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TblReferrals>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TblReferralStaffs)
            .WithOne(e => e.TblReferrals)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.IncidentId)
            .IsRequired();
    }

    public DbSet<MultipleRecords.Models.TblReferrals> TblReferrals { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<MultipleRecords.Models.TblReferralStaff> TblReferralStaff { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

It will generate two tables for you in database, and add the foreign key reference.

> 2 Bind the correct value in your razor pages

**Tbl.cshtml**

```
@page
@model MultipleRecords.Pages.TblModel
@{
}

<h1>This is TblReferrals</h1>

<form method="post" id="newReferralForm">

    <div class="row my-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Staff Names</label>
            @* For a clearer display, I directly popup the option value with numbers *@
            @* Here is the TblStaffList that is bound *@
            <select class="form-control staffReferral" multiple="multiple" asp-items="@Model.EsrRecords" asp-for="@Model.TblStaffList">
                <option value="1"> Num 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> Num 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> Num 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> Num 4 </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Incident Number</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Referral.IncidentId" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary fw-bold createReferral">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Tbl.cshtml.cs**

```
public class TblModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MultipleRecordsContext _db;

    public TblModel(MultipleRecordsContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public TblReferrals Referral { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> TblStaffList { get; set; }

    public SelectList EsrRecords { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post entered");

        //Considered that the <select> element with multiple="multiple" attribute can only bind to a list of simple types,
        //it is clearer to bind the value to a string list and initialize a referralstaff object
        
        //Your logic code
        …
        await _db.TblReferrals.AddAsync(referral);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Create a referral staff record for each selected staff number member.
        foreach (var staffAssignmentNumber in TblStaffList)
        {
            var referralStaff = new TblReferralStaff
            {
                AssignmentNumber = staffAssignmentNumber,
                IncidentId = Referral.IncidentId
            };
            await _db.TblReferralStaff.AddAsync(referralStaff);
        }

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); // Save referral staff records.

        return RedirectToPage("Index");

    }
}
```

Option selected

[image]

Value passed

[image]

Records stored

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ronaldoz, that was exactly what  I was looking for :)